# Executing signed VBA code on Mac without getting security notification

Tags: vba, macos, certificate, powerpoint, code-signing

My PowerPoint VBA code is signed with code signing Certificate (PFX) and converted into PPAM. This can be installed perfectly on Mac, but when executed it always prompts the scary macro security alert.

How can this signed VBA code be executed on Mac without getting security notification? Is there any way to trust the certificate and do not prompt anymore?

Environment: Office 365, MacOS Catalina

Comment: Sorry, that's not possible. The macOS supports code signing certificates for .app packages, but not VBA.

Comment: Thank you @JohnKorchok that seems to be the case (and Daniel seems to be wrong). I need to prove this to the customer -- (apart from the fact that I threw the money for the cert out the window hahaha).   Could you point me to an official document which states this -- I searched and even Apple support couldn't give me an info -- your input is very valuable for me.

Comment: Tank you @Ashish for editing my question

Comment: Official documents rarely state what software can't do, only what it can do. I have 20 years experience with digitally signed VBA, and I code VBA for both Mac and Windows. Perhaps your client will accept my statement. Office for Mac lacks the whole Trust Center configuration that makes VBA code signing work in Windows.

Comment: @JohnKorchok if you copy paste your comment as answer instead I will upvote it/mark it as correct answer.
I found also this:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/does-office-for-mac-support-trust-center-or-does/1fb2c9d8-f7d6-4d48-a651-2912013216be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that's not possible. The macOS supports code signing certificates for .app packages, but not VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate you used was (if not self signed) issued by a certificate authority. The issuer must be trusted (Issuer certificate must be known/installed) to prevent the message.

Comment: Thank you Daniel - The certificate was issued by GlobalSign. i did install the certificate in the Apple Keychain. Still there is no sign of the Mac understanding it in the PPT VBA -- Maybe @John Korchok is right?